# JScript compilation error nodejs command line tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

So I'm trying to build a command line tool using `node.js` but am running into problems trying to run the tool. Here's the simple code that I have.

src/main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

(function main() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
})();
```

and in my `packages.json` I have this added

```
"bin": {
    "test": "./src/main.js"
 }
```

But when I try and execute `test` from the command line I get a Microsoft JScript compilation error at line 1 char 1 invalid character code 800A03F6.

Any ideas what I might be missing? Thanks :)

Comment: How do you run this ? Seems like Windows Scripting Host processes your code, not Node

Comment: I just type `test` into the command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the information from this [tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/11/scripting-with-node/)

> npm install -g
>
> test
>
> Hello, world!

Did you try to install it before running it?

Comment: Oh nice thanks! Using `npm link` during development instead of `npm install -g` will be great too

Comment: Do mark it as answer if it correctly answered your question yea, cheers

Comment: Doesn't work for me.